# Unable to change values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix for coin change problem for Dynamic programming for Coursera assignment.

I'm able to create the dataframe and set the initial values for that.

But when iterating over the dataframe using for loops, i'm not able to change the values in its cells. It's using **.iloc[]** to go through rows and columns.

Here's what I have tried so far in creating dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
amount=int(input())
coins=list(map(int, input().split()))
matrix=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(len(coins), amount+1)), columns=list(range(0,amount+1)))
matrix.iloc[0]=matrix.columns
print(matrix)
for i in matrix.index[1:]:
    for j in matrix.columns[1:]:
        if j>=coins[i-1]:
            matrix.iloc[i,j]=min(matrix.iloc[i-1,j], matrix.iloc[i,j-i+1])
        else:
            matrix.iloc[i,j]=matrix.iloc[i-1,j]
print(matrix)
```

Comment: What kind of user input are you expecting? `int(input())` implies a single integer, but `map(int, input().split())` implies a string of space-separated integers. I can't test your code with either input type.

Comment: Hi @Tyrion2285, I tried running your code and it seems do work without throwing exceptions. So now the question is: what output did you expect? Why do you not like the output you are getting?